# How to connect to mysql on a BlueMix PHP app

Tags: ibm-cloud

What directive do I need to include to have the mysqli library available to my php app on BlueMix?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the following to your *composer.json* file:

```
  "require": {
    "ext-mysqli": "*"
  }
```

I suggest you to take also a look at [this](https://github.com/IBM-Bluemix/php-mysql) sample.